# storyboard linking buttons to .h

Tags: ios, storyboard

Hi i'm just a bit confused on the linking things from the storyboard to the ViewController.h. I've created a new single view application project and when I went to the storyboard I made a button. Now I went to the editor view and ctrl-draged the button onto my ViewController.h which worked. But when i created another view controller on the storyboard with a button on it, ctrl-drag does not work anymore. I've tried typing in myself, -(IBAction)test:(id)sender;, but it wouldn't let me connect to the button on my second view controller.

Comment: Can you post screenshot?!?

Comment: everything is the default setting, only thing i did was add a button and then created another view control on the storyboard with a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not set your class name in the VC settings. 
[image]

Comment: sorry but could you just explain a tiny bit more on that? since the original view controller on the storyboard has the class default to UIView and that works with the ViewController.h.

Comment: Your first view controller is connected up to ViewController because of the template you used when you first created the project.  You need to associate a view controller you create in interface builder to the actual view controller that handles it in code.  And that's exactly what the screenshot above shows you.  Change it to your new ViewController class and it will be good.

Comment: okay, I see what you are talking about. Yeah because when i clicked on the view control the class is UIView but if I click on the 2px line on the outer edge of the control it showed me UIViewController. Thanks for the explanation!